# Setup new Account Website Payment Pro account

Tags: soap, paypal

I have signed up and created a paypal developer and sandbox account. I am looking to develop a payment solution using Website Payment Flow that will accept credit card payments as well as Paypal Express Checkout. I plan to develop a SOAP solution and have prepare my first DoDirectPayment request. However when I try to submit the request I keep getting the response regardless of what values I passed in the SOAP body

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-    ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <Security xsi:type="wsse:SecurityType" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"/>
      <RequesterCredentials xsi:type="ebl:CustomSecurityHeaderType" xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
         <Credentials xsi:type="ebl:UserIdPasswordType" xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
            <Username xsi:type="xs:string">my_API_username</Username>
            <Password xsi:type="xs:string">my_API_password</Password>
            <Signature xsi:type="xs:string">my_API_signature</Signature>
            <Subject xsi:type="xs:string">?</Subject>
            <AuthToken xsi:type="xs:string">?</AuthToken>
         </Credentials>
      </RequesterCredentials>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body id="_0">
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Data type '' mismatch in element 'urn1:AddressOwner'</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Correction -  I am looking to develop a payment solution using "Website Payment Pro"

Comment: Disregard this item - I was passing some empty XML nodes on my request that were causing the error. I have corrected this and I am able to get a successful response